$f(X) \overset{D}{=} g(X)$ $\implies f=g$?
Let X be a continuous random variable and $$f(X) \overset{D}{=} g(X)$$ in distribution for two continuous functions $f,g$. Does it necessarily hold that $f(x)= a g(x) + b$ on the support of $X$ for some constants $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?
An interesting example is when X is Gaussian and $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$; then $f=-g$. But is there some weird case when $f\neq a\cdot g + b$?

No; take $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $f(x) = -\ln(x)$, $g(x) = -\ln(1-x)$.
Then $f(X) \overset{D}{=} g(X) \sim \text{Exp}(1)$, but $f$ is not an affine map of $g$ on the support of $X$.
